# PhantomJS package - converting html to pdf issue

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using [PhantomJS](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) Package for converting an HTML page to pdf. I'm using below code for generating the pdf file.

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  await page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1024, height: 600 });
  const status = await page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  console.log(`Page opened with status [${status}].`);

  await page.render('stackoverflow.pdf');
  console.log(`File created at [./stackoverflow.pdf]`);

  await instance.exit();
})()
```

Using above code pdf generated successfully. **But the page of the generated pdf is too long not A4 size. Can you please let me how to resolve this issue.**

To view the generated PDF - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RfKZd5ZPFpYDOkiPR6mFt_5M0BhRbTXQ/view

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [page paperSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html).

> paperSize {object}
>
> This property defines the size of the web page when rendered as a PDF.

```
page.paperSize = {
  width: '8.267in',
  height: '11.692in',
  margin: {
    top: '50px',
    left: '20px'
  }
};
```